# Uso do $rootscope AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Gostaria de saber se é correto utilizar o `$rootscope` desta forma?

```
$scope.buscaChamados = function() {
                        modelSac.buscaChamados()
                          .success(function(data, res) {
                            $rootScope.chamadosSistema = data;
                          });
                       }
```

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que você esteja se referindo a boas práticas. Se este for o caso, eu imagino que o que você deseja fazer (compartilhar dados com outros escopos) pode ser melhor implementado via `service` (ou, alternativamente, um `factory`).

Em várias implementações o $rootScope é reservado para uso como um *pipeline* para *broadcasts* globais.